# VBA macro called in Outlook not sorting in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, tablesorter

So basically I have an excel object called xlobj, and in my code before this snippit if I am referring to the xlobj I would say

```
xlobj.Range(blahh blahh blahh).Value = "something"
```

Now my goal is to sort all my values that I took using the rest of my script from newest to oldest in Excel.  I used the record macro function in excel to get the macro code, then pasted it in my Outlook VBA and attached the xlobj.*_*  infront of all of the necessary codelines.

It doesn't work, it does everything but the physical sorting (selection happens and the code is compiling)

```
xlobj.Range("A2:E900").Select
xlobj.Sort.SortFields.Clear
xlobj.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=xlobj.Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With xlobj.Sort
  .SetRange xlobj.Range("A2:E900")
  .Header = xlNo
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With
```

Does anyone see the problem with the code?

*EDIT*

```
Private Sub Extract(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder)

On Error Resume Next
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
Set MyFolder = oFolder

Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application.14")
Set xlobjWbk = xlobj.Workbooks.Open("c:\Users\(username)\Desktop\(filename).xlsx")
xlobj.Visible = True
xlobj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Set Heading
xlobj.Range("a" & 1).Value = "Recieved Time"
xlobj.Range("b" & 1).Value = "Sender Email"
xlobj.Range("c" & 1).Value = "Subject"
xlobj.Range("d" & 1).Value = "Sender Name"
xlobj.Range("e" & 1).Value = "Body"
 xlobj.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 17
 xlobj.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 32
 xlobj.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 36
 xlobj.Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 19
 xlobj.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 56

For i = MyFolder.Items.Count To MyFolder.Items.Count + 100
 xlobj.Range("a" & i + 1).Value = ""
 xlobj.Range("b" & i + 1).Value = ""
 xlobj.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = ""
 xlobj.Range("d" & i + 1).Value = ""
 xlobj.Range("e" & i + 1).Value = ""
Next

For i = 1 To MyFolder.Items.Count
 Set myItem = MyFolder.Items(i)
 msgtext = myItem.body

 xlobj.Range("a" & i + 1).Value = myItem.ReceivedTime
 xlobj.Range("b" & i + 1).Value = myItem.SenderEmailAddress
 xlobj.Range("C" & i + 1).Value = myItem.Subject
 xlobj.Range("d" & i + 1).Value = myItem.SenderName
 xlobj.Range("e" & i + 1).Value = msgtext
 xlobj.Columns("A:E").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
Next

xlobj.Range("A2:E900").Select
xlobj.Sort.SortFields.Clear
xlobj.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=xlobj.Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,     Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With xlobj.Sort
    .SetRange xlobj.Range("A1:E900")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

This script goes to the folder passed in through the parameter, and then dumps the inbox into an excel sheet

Comment: Might I ask to see what code you had *before* this block? I'm wondering if `xlobj` was set to the right instance of Excel/the correct worksheet within. I could be wrong (why I want to see more code), but it looks like you should have something more like `xlobj.Sheets(1).Range(blahh blahh blahh)`

Answer (score 0):

```
With xlobj.Sort
    .SetRange xlobj.Range("A1:E900") '<---
    .Header = xlYes                  '<---
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: this didn't change anything.  The .SetRange should be A2 because A1's row are headers.  I don't want to sort the headers, I want to sort the data (dates) that are in the columns below each header

Comment: Setting .Header to xlYes tells Excel you have a header row, so it *won't* sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Change to xlobj.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=xlobj.Range("A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,     Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal